# "Repulse" VS "Repel"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

I know that the two verbs "repulse" and "repel" both can be used when negative energies are approaching you in the same sense, but I need to know how each word alters the meaning of the bold sentence below? (Based in dictionary definitions, they both mean the same to me, but I was wondering how do you think of them?)

> - Try and find a way to attract positive people. This is a good step forward to protect yourself from those people who should not be around you. Give them all a wide berth. On top of that, **you should be able to ......... negative energies from yourself**.

a. repel 
b. repulse

Please let me know if they are interchangeable here or there is some preferences and tips that I need to bear in mind.

Comment: This question has been asked on the sister site [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464458/whats-different-between-repel-and-repulse/464473).

Comment: Thank you very much @Weather Vane, I reviewed your provided thread, but the only thing that seemed to be  considerable there (at least to me,) was that "repel" is more intentional, while "repulse" is more of an unintentional force. If so, both words work here, however "repel" is definitely a better option here compared to "repulse". What do you think of them and how do you see my take?

Comment: I tend to think that "repel" is when you fight or push someone off, but when you "repulse" someone it probably does not get to the stage of having to repel them, because they don't want to approach you. That's an opinion, though.